# Autohotkey Direction For Microsoft Photo Navigation With Keys In Zoom Mode

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, microsoft, keyboard-navigation

Microsoft Photos does not allow navigating through pictures if you are zoomed in into one, only when you are at default zoom level. This is a bit confusing, so I decided to create a Authotkey direction to smooth this issue out.

Since the scroll wheel always navigates through items in Microsoft Photos (for whathever reason), my logic was to always trigger the mousewheel scroll when a navigation (arrow) key is pressed. In theory, this works great, in reality however, it doesn't work.

Does anyone know why? Is the Autohotkey direction wrong or is it something else?

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Microsoft.Photos.exe
Left::Send {WheelUp}
Right::Send {WheelDown}
#If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#If (WinGetActiveProcessName() = "Microsoft.Photos.exe")

    Left::Send {WheelUp}
    Right::Send {WheelDown}

#If


WinGetActiveProcessName(){ 
; https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=13818&p=70912#p73137 
    WinGet name, ProcessName, A
    if (name = "ApplicationFrameHost.exe")
    {
        ControlGet hwnd, Hwnd,, Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow1, A
        if hwnd 
        {
            WinGet name, ProcessName, ahk_id %hwnd%
        }
    }
    return name
}
```

Comment: It works, awesome! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

Photos is a strange app, calling another executable that is not the obvious
one.

This was tested and will work :

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe ApplicationFrameHost.exe
Left::Send {WheelUp}
Right::Send {WheelDown}
```

The Application Frame Host is a Windows service that is designed
to display certain applications in frames.
Note that modifying how this generic executable works might affect
other Windows applications.

---

Another possibility is to go by the title containing the
string "Photos", rather than by the executable:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, Photos
Left::Send {WheelUp}
Right::Send {WheelDown}
```

Comment: There is a slight problem with this solution. Unfortunately, also other Software is triggered by this, for example Adobe XD which is very annoying (of course). Do you perhaps have another idea to target MIcrosoft Photo more specifically?

Comment: Yes, `ApplicationFrameHost.exe` was probably a bad choice. I added another one.