# Is there any command line to open an existing image with Snip & Sketch?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, windows-store-app

Is there any command line to open an existing image with Snip & Sketch?
Or better if you could open Snip & Sketch and paste an image from clipboard to Snip & Sketch.

Comment: Why not just save the image.   Once saved you can open it any time.  Save is a Snip & Sketch function

Comment: @John I capture the image from another app (which is better) but I want to edit with Snip & Sketch. It would be ideal if I don't have to save it and just open Snip & Sketch and paste it. If it's not possible it's ok to save it and then open with Snip & Sketch but I still don't know how to open an existing image with Snip & Sketch from command line.

Comment: @BlindSpots but Snip & Sketch is from  Microsoft App store so you don't have the `exe` as  the snipping tool.

Comment: @BlindSpots yes I did, `Run ScreenSketch.exe` does not work.

Comment: I always just save whenever I get some item into Snip & Sketch

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar to this previously and mapped an AutoHotkey shortcut to open whatever was on the clipboard in IrfanView (since IrfanView has commandline options to be able to paste directly from the clipboard).

I'm pretty sure that what you'd like to do is technically feasible, and AutoHotkey is relatively easy to use for mapping shortcut keys and could be used to glue everything together.

A rough outline for a scripted approach would be as follows:

1. Use IrfanView as an intermediate program. Paste the clipboard and save it to disk via commandline without showing an actual GUI window (I didn't double-check, but I'm pretty sure this is possible)
2. Figure out how to launch ScreenSketch. It is a UWP app so you may have to do some sleuthing to figure out how to launch it from explorer (i.e., launch it as a shell command or via the 'run' command in AutoHotkey).  For example: https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/open-uwp-apps-from-command-line-windows-10/
3. ScreenSketch may support a commandline option to load a file from disk, or more likely it doesn't. You could try it out just by testing it once you have a shortcut (by passing it an image path\filename as a parameter), but let's assume that doesn't work and that you are only able to start the ScreenSketch.exe program with nothing loaded
4. Using AutoHotkey, after launching ScreenSketch you would wait until the window was active. This could be done via time delay (and hope it appears and is active), but it would be better to check for either ApplicationFrameHost.exe (generic), or check for the correct ScreenSketch.exe name (specific), which could be done by adapting a function such as the one found in the suggested solutions here: [Autohotkey Direction For Microsoft Photo Navigation With Keys In Zoom Mode](https://superuser.com/questions/1757918/autohotkey-direction-for-microsoft-photo-navigation-with-keys-in-zoom-mode)
5. Once the ScreenSketch application is active, AutoHotkey would then need to send Ctrl+O to open a file dialog, then wait for the dialog (via `WinWaitActive`), then send the path of wherever the temp file was saved in Step 1, and finally send `{Enter}` to open that file
6. At that point, if everything above worked, whatever was on the clipboard when the script was called would be open in ScreenSketch for editing, and the function call for items 1-5 above could be mapped to any shortcut of your choosing using AutoHotkey, once it was coded as a routine